# how to format the number with comma when user lost focus in <h:inputText>

Tags: jsf-2, format, numbers, jsf-1.2

I want to format number with comma in jsf  
eg: when i type 100000 in the text field and when i go other field, the text field should display 100,000.
I know it can be done in javascript, but I wonder know whether it can be done by jsf build in function. I try the  with groupingUsed="true", but still doesn't work for me.

here is some of my jsf code:

```
    <h:outputLabel for="testing" value="testing ID *" />                      
    <h:inputText id="testing" required="true" label="testing" value="#{user.testing}" style="width:200px"  >  
      <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" for="testing"  /> 
    </h:inputText>
```

edited: I wish to know how to do in jsf 1.2 and jsf 2 both version.

Comment: Do you want to submit the value and format it on the server side? Or to format it using javascript?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="###,###" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it only work after i click some commandbutton.
I want it changes like onblur=""

Answer (score 0):

Without the Ajax capability of JSF 2.0, I think you should use a combination of client-side JavaScript and JSF's `Converter`. The client-side script will be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function convertFormat() {
      // function to add comma 
   }
</script>

<h:inputText id="testing" required="true" label="testing" value="#{user.testing}" style="width:200px" onblur="convertFormat();" />
```

And on the server side you should have a `Converter` to get the original number:

```
@FacesConverter("converter.numberFormatConverter")
public class NumberFormatConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {        
        value = value.replaceAll(",", "");
        return Long.parseLong(value); 
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // add back the comma
    }

}
```

Your `getAsObject` method is the place for you to convert from HTML's input text to the type of input that you want (I used `Long` in my example). The `getAsString` method is the place for you to do the opposite thing.

I will let you figure out on your own how to add `,` in the client-side script. Hope this helps!

Comment: greet!! it able to work in jsf version 2 but it doesn't work in jsf version 1.2 as 1.2 no support for tag f:ajax
do u have other solutions for jsf version 1.2?? thanks a lot :)

Comment: @xin_yao I have just updated my answer. When you ask a question, please add the proper tag. We have a tag for `jsf1.2`. :)

Comment: @xin_yao Use Richfaces and a4j:ajax to adding this behavior.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes, thanks for the answer.
Actually I wish to know the solutions in both version 1.2 and 2. I do tried the javascript method already, just wonder to know whether jsf 1.2 can done by its built in function :)

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov, thanks for your answer, but I never try richfaces before, will try for it when free :)